# Is there any way to get backward and forward event in ie brower

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

Now i want to capture back and forward event in ie, i try to use BHO and js, but all did not work.
In chrome brower,there is some api like "forward/backward","reload","typed","autobookmark", but in ie, how can i get those event,thanks very much.